# Unable to draw on the image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlabel

What actually i need to do is...
Draw on the image(which is usually big in size). I need to scroll the image to draw on it.
For this purpose I added the image(JLabel) into a Jpanel and added the Jpanel into a JScrollPane.
Now I am able to scroll the image but not able to draw on it. Can someone please help me in figurring out it!! Here is my code...`

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");  
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800)); 

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 

    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image))); 

    JScrollPane jspane=new JScrollPane(panel);
    jspane.setViewportView(panel);
    jspane.add(this); //where i need to draw according to the mouse click
                      //when i tried frame.add(this); i was able to draw only on some  
                      //portion of the image but not able to scroll it.
    frame.add(jspane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();  

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

> jspane.add(this);

Don't try adding components to a scrollpane. Components can only be added to the viewport (and you did that when you created the JScrollPane.

If you want to draw on the label, then you need to extend JLabel and override the paintComponent() method to do your custom painting on top of the image.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for an example.